# How to apply group by here?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a table Movie with columns `Movie` and `Viewer` where each movie is viewed by any user any number of times, so the table can have multiple same entries. I want to find the Top N most viewed movies and then the Top K viewers for each of the Top N movies. How can I apply group by or partition by effectively in such scenario ? Or if there is any better approach to this, please share. Thanks!

| Movie | User |
| --- | --- |
| Avengers | John |
| Batman | Chris |
| Batman | Ron |
| X-Men | Chris |
| X-Men | Ron |
| Matrix | John |
| Batman | Martin |
| Matrix | Chris |
| Batman | Chris |
| X-Men | Ron |

So, in this table Batman is the most watched movie is Batman followed by X-Men so I want the result table to look like :

| Movie | User | View count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Batman | Chris | 2 |
| Batman | Ron | 1 |
| Batman | Martin | 1 |
| X-Men | Ron | 2 |
| X-Men | Chris | 1 |
| Matrix | John | 1 |
| Matrix | Chris | 1 |
| Avengers | John | 1 |

I understand that I can group by movie and then do order by count(*) desc but this doesn't give me the second column which is grouped by viewer and the count for each viewer also.

Comment: It might help to show your table structures and some sample data. What have you tried and where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: Added the table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach (assuming Top 3 movies with Top 2 users)

```
select movie, user, view_count
from (
  select distinct *,  
    count(*) over(partition by movie) movie_views,
    count(*) over(partition by movie, user) view_count
  from your_table
)
qualify dense_rank() over(order by movie_views desc) <=3 
and row_number() over(partition by movie order by view_count desc) <=2
-- order by movie_views desc, view_count desc
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Although this answer is exactly what I was expecting but I am getting `Column resource of type STRUCT cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT` error in Big Query editor. Any thoughts on that ?

Comment: sample data presented in your question does not have any structs thus proposed solution uses distinct.

Comment: "Structs" - yes, I could figure out the cause, once again thank you so much for your quick response and all the help on so many of my questions. Respect.